# CheckStyle 5.7.0. with Java 8

Tags: eclipse-plugin, java-8, checkstyle

I am using Checkstyle Plug-in 5.7.0 in eclipse with Java 8. I am getting `Got an exception - expecting EOF, found 'throw'` in my interface default method. Can you please help me how to fix my checkstyle. Following is the method

```
default void validate(final String fieldName) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(fieldValue)) {
        throw new RuntimeException(""); //check style error here
    }
}
```

Even if I remove the method body, i get the same error on the ending brace. It seems that checkstyle is not supporting a method with body in interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not your fault - Checkstyle does not support Java 8 syntax yet. (This is true for version 5.7, which is the most current version at the time of this writing.)

However, the Checkstyle team and especially the contributors are [working hard on it](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/10), and Java 8 support is announced to be released before October 15, 2014 (according to the October 4 comment by Roman Ivanov, one of the Checkstyle committers).

So,  think the best strategy is to wait for a few more days. :-)

Comment: There you are: [Checkstyle 5.9](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/releasenotes.html#Release_5.9)